# Comic book identification - huge man with axe, white hair, defending beseiged walls

Tags: story-identification, comics

This is a comic book I read no later than 1993 (so is pre-1993).

And probably after 1988 though I can't be certain.

The protagonist is a huge barbarian with an axe, who seems like an old man, who is defending a series of gigantic walls against an invading army, apparently single-handedly. They keep having to fall back to inner walls. He has to get a massage at one point (not that kind of comic btw).

It's not a super-hero or funny comic, it's more of a serious graphic novel.

That's about it, sorry it's so vague.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think this is the Graphic Novel adaption of the first of Drenai series by David Gemmell the Novel is called [Legend](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legend_(Gemmell_novel)), and the adaptation is  [David Gemmell's Legend A Graphic Novel](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3477255-david-gemmell-s-legend)

The Fortress of Dros Delnoch guards a mountain pass that is all that blocks the Nadir Horde commanded by Ulric Khan from invading the Kingdom of the Drenai.
 Amongst the defenders of the undermanned fortress are the monks of the Temple of the Thirty, and Druss Captain of the Axe. Druss is a mid 60s year old man who has spent a much of his life fighting and has come to die in one last battle rather than face the ravages of old age.

He does not defend the fortress single handily but is a major motivating factor in rallying the garrison to protect the walls. It contains a scene where Druss is massaged due to the arthritis in his back causing him pain, which is reducing his ability to fight.

It was one year later than your timeline but I think it's close enough.

Comment: I didn't realise there was a graphic novel version, but the description definitely reminded me of the book. First published in 1993 so could have easily be read in 1993.

Comment: @Jack I was only familiar with the graphic novel as I was a fan of the book.

Comment: This is it. Legend.